# Is "be more use to" idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language

I came across a sentence in a novel:

> You have a concussion and **are more use to** the Navy with a working brain than without, plus you're 'bout as dinged up as that ship is. Look at your shoulder. (*The Beautiful Mistake*, by Steve Zingerman)

I thought **are more use to** reads strange to me, because **be of more use to** is a more common expression.

Answer (score -1):

Your two examples have very different meanings

> You have a concussion and **are more use to** the Navy with a working brain than without

has the meaning,

> ***you have a disability, but are more familiar with dealing with the Navy without your disability.***

the perspective is how you deal with the Navy, where as

> You have a concussion and **would be of more use to** the Navy with a working brain than without

has the meaning of your usefulness to the Navy.

Comment: Shouldn't that first one be _used to_, not _use to_?